# Intel HAXM not working on mac high sierra 10.9.5

Tags: android, macos

I have MacBook Pro running High Sierra 10.9.5

I have installed Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM) version 6.2.1 
but when I try to run the AVD it says `Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD`.

Unknown Error and when I go to Android Virtual Device Manager under the target for column it says `Android null(Google Play)`. I have checked a lot of solutions from different places but nothing seems to be working.
Please help me I am new to Android .

Comment: you have to install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM)

Comment: @Tej I said in the question that I have already installed Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM) version 6.2.1

Comment: I haven't downvoted you . so cool . Im just  helping you  out

Comment: Now check . Is Intel virtualization on your mac  enable or not

Comment: I haven't check but I thought CPU Virtualization is enabled by default

Comment: MacOS 10.9.5 is Mavericks not High Sierra

Answer (score 2):

Not all intel processors have the HAXM available. If your computer supports this you should be able to see it on your bios.

1. Restart the computer
2. Get in the bios (pressing f2 or delete of escape key multiple times) while the os is loading.
3. You will look in your bios for something called VT or virtualization technology you have to enable it.

If you do not see any changes sometimes this feature have a "bug" so you have to repeat the step 1. and 2. then disable again VT, restart (let the OS do the complete charge) and then again repeat step 1. and 2. and enable again VT.

If this doesn't help there are other things that could be happening... you can check it on:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows